# Can I add an outlet to a sink disposal circuit for a TV?

Tags: electrical, wiring, receptacle, nec

I want to add an outlet for a TV in the living room. In the same stud bay on the other side of the wall in the kitchen is the switch for the disposal. The disposal circuit (20A) also feeds the dishwasher and a light above the sink. Can I use this circuit to feed the new TV outlet?
The village uses the 2011 NEC with no relevant amendments.

Comment: While not an optimal situation, I think it would be ok, since a TV only draws less than an amp.  I'll let the electricians give a definitive answer.

Comment: There's a non-zero chance that you'll get power issues with the TV every time the disposal or dishwasher runs. You may even get interference every time a pump or motor turns on in the dishwasher. A UPS between the outlet & TV will help cover the brownouts and clean up the power caused by appliance usage on the other side of the wall.

Answer (score 1):

So long as none of the devices on the circuit use more than 10A (half the breaker capacity, at which point the circuit is supposed to be "dedicated" to that single device, not shared (so it would already be improper if any of them are)) you *can.*

It's clearly not the "required countertop outlet circuits" which are restricted to only serving the kitchen if that's all it serves.

I don't think it's particularly *wise.* While modern TVs are not all that fussy, it's still not a great idea to put them on the same circuit as a heavy motor that may inject noise into the power as it starts and stops.

Comment: Also... If you're thinking of doing it by installing a switch-and-outlet combination to replace the existing switch, you may discover that it's a switch loop with no neutral, making that impossible without pulling new wire. Been there, done that.

Comment: A dedicated circuit can also be required if the appliance manual specifies that one is required.

Comment: Or if local inspector says one is required.